# JQuery Ajax Not Sending Data to Database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am almost done. I am GETTING the data using Ajax, but I am having an issue POSTING it. Here is my code. The AJAX POST is not sending anything to the page. I am certain that the .val() ids are correct, and I think my POSTCOMMENT function is correct too.

JQuery:

```
$(function()
{
    var userName = $('#username').val();
    var userId = $('#userid').val();
    var comment = $('#textareacomment').val();

    $("#submitcomment").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:'api/postprofilecomment.php',
            data: {"userId" : userId, "comment" : comment},
            success: function(result, status){
                $('usercommentdiv').append('<li id="comment">' + userName + ':' + comment + '</li>');

            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP POST PAGE:

```
<?php
include ("../db/database.php");
include ("../classes/profilecommentclass.php");

session_start();
$userId = json_decode($_POST['userId']);
$comment = json_decode($_POST['comment']);
$profileCommentHandler = new ProfileComment($db, $userId);
$profileCommentHandler->postComment($userId, $comment);
?>
```

POST COMMENT FUNCTION:

```
function postComment($userId, $comment)
{
  $this->time = date(format,timestamp);
  $sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO profile_comment(user_id, profile_comment, time_added, time_updated)" .
  "VALUES (:userId, :comment, :timeAdded, :timeUpdated)";
  $sqlPrepare = $this->db->prepare($sqlStatement);
  $sqlPrepare->bindParam(':userId', $userId);
  $sqlPrepare->bindParam(':comment', $comment);
  $sqlPrepare->bindParam(':timeAdded', $this->time);
  $sqlPrepare->bindParam(':timeUpdated', $this->time);
  $sqlPrepare->execute();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the "PHP post page" is not receiving the data? Or is the AJAX `success` callback not working?

Comment: Not showing success or failure

Comment: You have a typo in `success`. You have `apprend` (the "r") instead of `append`.

Comment: I correct it, still not working (updated main post)

Comment: Added a ")" at the end of the Ajax function, and now it is returning success, but still not making it to the database. (Updated main post)

Comment: I alerted out the comment and userId vars, and it is showing the correct data.

Comment: I know for a fact now that it is an error in the postComment() function, because I placed it on a test page, and it is not working, but returning no errors.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the values of `$userId, $comment` in your PHP function?

Comment: Yes, but the PHP Comment Function is not working for some reason. That is the problem, because I have it on a test page with dummy data, and it won't send anything to the database, but yet it is not showing any php errors. I am trying to make sure it isn't a database structural issue, but it is NOT executing.

Comment: if(sqlPrepare->execute)
{
echo "Working"
}
else
{echo "Not Working}"......is not returning anything

Comment: did you console the logs in ajax success function >

Comment: I alerted it, and the data popped up correctly. No errors showing in developer tool either.

Comment: what is your problem then.. appending it to the div in success function?

Comment: I don't see the post php page returning any data. what are you expecting to fill with list which you are trying to append. normally ajax function used to fetch data from db and appending it do the web page

Comment: Thanks Aroon, I am going to take the append off.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\profilecommentclass.php:99 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\profilecommentclass.php(99): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\api\postprofilecomment.php(9): ProfileComment->postComment(NULL, NULL) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\profilecommentclass.php on line 99

...................(Line 99 is the execute())

Comment: Ok, the jquery data is showing success, but not getting to the PHP page. I know this because I entered a dummy user_id, and it went from saying the user_id is null to the profile_comment is null.

Comment: you identified the error right.. do you need any other help'

Comment: Yes, why isn't this succesful jquery data not going to .php page.

Comment: what do you mean by not going to .php? try something like this in your php page just echo "success" in the post comment func. in ajax function do console.log(result). then let me know what you are getting

Comment: result isn't showing anything, only the .val() vars are displaying in console/alert.

Comment: The result is returning undefined, but the .val() vars are not.

Comment: run PHP post page with manual userid and comment. do echo at the end of the script. let's check where you r doing wrong

Comment: Solved!!!! I needed onClick in the action form. Comrades, thanks for all your help and input. It helped me impove a lot.